# Converting NSNumber to Double(CLLocationDegrees)

Tags: json, swift, double, nsnumber, cllocation

I'm trying to add latitude and longitude to annotations on my map.
My data is JSON type

```
 "{\"lat\": 25.0437396, \"lng\": 121.5308224}"
```

I transform it into a dictionary first

```
["lat": 25.0437396, "lng": 121.5308224]
```

and use the value in dictionary to add

```
var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
let latNum = shopCoordinate["lat"] as! NSNumber
let lngNum = shopCoordinate["lng"] as! NSNumber
let lat = latNum as? Double
let lng = lngNum as? Double
coordinate.latitude = lat!
coordinate.longitude = lng!
```

But the Double type value would become like this, and don't show on map

```
25.043739599999999, 121.53082240000001
```

I can't cast it to other type instead, since CLLocationDegrees accepts a double type. It drives my crazy. If someone could give me any advice, I would be really really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply convert it to a `Double` directly?

```
if let latNum = shopCoordinate["lat"] as? Double, let lngNum = shopCoordinate["lng"] as? Double {
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latNum, longitude: lngNum)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You just need to cast your data into `Double` and not `NSNumber`, like so:

```
var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
let lat = shopCoordinate["lat"] as! Double
let lng = shopCoordinate["lng"] as! Double
coordinate.latitude = lat
coordinate.longitude = lng
```

Comment: I kept worrying about losing precision after casting. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Satty 25.043739599999999 it is the same as 25.0437396